# Class path reference issue when deploying Orbeon form PE in Liferay EE

Tags: java, deployment, liferay, orbeon

I followed the [installation manual](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/deployment-portlet) to deploy Orbeon PE trial in Liferay EE 6.1.2 (JBoss AS 7.1). After I dropped orbeon.war in the deploy folder, I got the following reference error.

```
08:31:07,443 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) Class Path entry avalon-framework-4.1.5.jar in "/D:/liferay-portal-jboss-6.1.20-ee-ga2-20120731110418084/liferay-portal-6.1.20-ee-ga2/jboss-7.1.1/standalone/deployments/orbeon.war/WEB-INF/lib/barcode4j-1.0.jar"  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
```

The deployment process failed. Anyone come across such problem?

```
08:31:09,248 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "orbeon.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.orbeon.orbeon.env.jdbc.dbjboss.naming.context.java.my-databaseMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.module.orbeon.orbeon.env.jdbc.dbjboss.naming.context.java.my-database]"]}
08:31:09,393 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment orbeon.war in 144ms
08:31:09,394 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.naming.context.java.my-database (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.module.orbeon.orbeon.env.jdbc.db]

08:31:09,399 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.orbeon.orbeon.env.jdbc.dbjboss.naming.context.java.my-databaseMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.module.orbeon.orbeon.env.jdbc.dbjboss.naming.context.java.my-database]"]}}}
```

Comment: The first error is just a warning (it does say WARN after all) and I don't think it's the cause of the subsequent issues. However the second error seems to say there is an issue with a JDBCresource:  "java.module.orbeon.orbeon.env.jdbc.dbjboss.naming.context.java.my-databaseMissing". What is this `my-databaseMissing` entry? Is that something you configured? It's not something configured in Orbeon Forms.